# Gated buffer SN74LVC1G125 seems not to work with ADXL357 SPI connection. What is going on?

Tags: spi, buffer, accelerometer, teensy

N.B. this question is cross posted from [Analog Devices forum](https://ez.analog.com/mems/f/q-a/566586/gated-buffer-sn74lvc1g125-seems-not-to-work-with-adxl357-spi-connection-what-is-going-on), but wasn't expecting much answer there so I'm also putting it here. Hope that's okay.

I have a PCB prototype whereby an [ADXL357](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl356-357.pdf) is connected via SPI to an MK20DX256 MCU.  It has an [SN74LVC1G125](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn74lvc1g125) gated buffer attached to it, as recommended in the ADXL357 datasheet. The ADXL357 is sharing the SPI bus with an [ADXL373](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl373.pdf) (which does not have a gated buffer attached, because the datasheet didn't recommend that). When I try to read out the device ID for both devices, the ADXL373 returns the correct device ID. The ADXL357 does not.

EDIT: I get the "Error ADXL357 etc" while loop response. I can't remember what Device ID is returned (don't have the setup here) but it doesn't match the value that is on the datasheet.

Then I recreated the circuit on a breadboard, consisting of a Teensy 3.2, [ADXL357 EVAL](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/EVAL-ADXL356-357-UG-1119.pdf) and [ADXL373 EVAL](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/eval-adxl373z-ug-1980.pdf) sharing the same SPI bus. However, this time there was no gated buffer attached. In this case, both the ADXL357 and the ADXL373 returned the correct device ID.

This leads me to wonder if a) there is something wrong with my gated buffer implementation and b) if the gated buffer recommendation (from the datasheet) is wrong.

Any clues to what might be going on?

See schematics. I have highlighted the SPI connections on the MCU side.

Any help much appreciated!

EDIT: The code (now added) for the PCB and the breadboard setup is the same, with the only difference being that the PCB outputs to the debug monitor (UART) via `Serial1`, whereas the breadboard setup outputs via the USB serial interface (`Serial`). [See here](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_uart.html) for explanation on difference.

EDIT: Another thing I tried, is that I carefully removed the gated buffer from the PCB with some pliers. Then I wired the SCLK line together to restore the SPI connection as if the gated buffer had never been there. However that didn't change the outcome. Then I also removed the 10kOhm pullup resistor on the ADXL357 CS line, but that didn't change things either.

EDIT: I haven't tried monitoring the SPI line with a logic analyser yet (I do have one) because it's very difficult to attach the wires to points on the PCB for analysis.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Main .ino Arduino file**

```c
#include "ADXL373_SPI.h"
#include "ADXL357_SPI.h"
#include "debugLED.h"
#include "debugMonitor.h"


#define LED_PIN               7     

/* impact sensor */
#define ADXL373_CS_PIN        8  

/* BV sensor */
#define ADXL357_CS_PIN        9    

debugLED      dbLED(LED_PIN); 

debugMonitor   dbMon(DEBUG_SERIAL_USB);  // USB or Serial 1

/* Impact Sensor, SPI*/
ADXL373 hImSen(ADXL373_CS_PIN, 1); 
/* BV sensor */
ADXL357  bvSen(ADXL357_CS_PIN);


void setup()
{
  /* General MCU stuff */
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  dbLED.high(); 
  delay(3000);  
  dbMon.debugPrintln("Starting test program");
  delay(3000); 
  

  while (!bvSen.testConnection()) { 
    dbMon.debugPrintln("Error ADXL357 sensor set up");
    dbLED.blinkStartMCU(); 
    Serial.println(bvSen.readDeviceID(), HEX); 
  }


  while(!hImSen.testConnection()){
    dbMon.debugPrintln("Error ADXL373 sensor set up");
    dbLED.blinkStartMCU(); 
  }
  dbLED.high(); 
  

}

void loop()
{
  // Do nothing
  dbMon.debugPrintln("Looping - setup successful");
  delay(5000); 
}

//****************************************
```

**ADXL357_SPI.h**

```cpp
/*

    Copyright (c) 2019 Seeed Technology Co., Ltd.
    Website    : www.seeed.cc
    Author     : downey
    Create Time: Jan 2018
    Change Log :

    The MIT License (MIT)

    Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
    of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
    in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
    to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
    copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
    furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

    The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
    all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
    IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
    FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
    AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
    LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
    OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
    THE SOFTWARE.
*/

#ifndef __ADXL357_SPI_H
#define __ADXL357_SPI_H


#include <Arduino.h> 
#include "SPI.h"

#define ADXL357_PARTID            0xED 
#define ADXL357_DEV_MEMS_REG_ADDR         0x01
#define ADXL357_DEV_ID_REG_ADDR           0x02
#define ADXL357_DEV_VERSION_ID_REG_ADDR   0x03
#define ADXL357_STATUS_REG_ADDR           0x04
#define ADXL357_FIFO_ENTRY_REG_ADDR       0x05 // Mistake in original code. It said 0x06 (temp)

#define ADXL357_ACT_EN_REG_ADDR           0x24 // Enable activity interrupt (register address)
#define ADXL357_SET_INT_PIN_MAP_REG_ADDR  0x2a

#define ADXL357_ACT_THRESH_H_REG_ADDR     0x25
#define ADXL357_ACT_THRESH_L_REG_ADDR     0x26
#define ADXL357_ACT_COUNT_REG_ADDR        0X27

#define ADXL357_X_DATA_REG_ADDR           0x08
#define ADXL357_FIFO_DATA_REG_ADDR        0x11

#define ADXL357_POWER_CTR_REG_ADDR        0x2d

#define ADXL357_TEMPERATURE_REG_ADDR      0x06
#define ADXL357_FILTER_REG_ADDR           0x28

#define ADXL357_FIFO_SAMPLES_REG  0x29 

#define ADXL357_SET_RANGE_REG_ADDR        0x2c
#define ADXL357_RESET_REG_ADDR            0x2f

/* Interrupt function map register  */
#define ADXL357_ACT_EN2_BIT               7
#define ADXL357_OVR_EN2_BIT               6
#define ADXL357_FULL_EN2_BIT              5
#define ADXL357_RDY_EN2_BIT               4
#define ADXL357_ACT_EN1_BIT               3         // Activity interrupt enable on pin 1 
#define ADXL357_OVR_EN1_BIT               2
#define ADXL357_FULL_EN1_BIT              1
#define ADXL357_RDY_EN1_BIT               0

/* Filtering settings */
#define ADXL357_HPF_CORNER                4        // Bit position of high pass filter 
#define ADXL357_HPF_CORNER_NA             0b000    // No high pass filter enabled
#define ADXL357_HPF_CORNER_5              0b001    // 24.7 × 10−4 × ODR
#define ADXL357_HPF_CORNER_4              0b010    // 6.2084 × 10−4 × ODR
#define ADXL357_HPF_CORNER_3              0b011    // 1.5545 × 10−4 × ODR
#define ADXL357_HPF_CORNER_2              0b100    // 0.3862 × 10−4 × ODR
#define ADXL357_HPF_CORNER_1              0b101    // 0.0954 × 10−4 × ODR
#define ADXL357_HPF_CORNER_0              0b110    // 0.0238 × 10−4 × ODR

#define ADXL357_ODR_LPF                   0        // Bit position of ODR and low-pass filter corner
#define ADXL357_ODR_4000HZ_LPF            0b0000  
#define ADXL357_ODR_2000HZ_LPF            0b0001
#define ADXL357_ODR_1000HZ_LPF            0b0010
#define ADXL357_ODR_500HZ_LPF             0b0011  
#define ADXL357_ODR_250HZ_LPF             0b0100  
#define ADXL357_ODR_125HZ_LPF             0b0101  
#define ADXL357_ODR_62HZ_LPF              0b0110  
#define ADXL357_ODR_31HZ_LPF              0b0111  
#define ADXL357_ODR_15HZ_LPF              0b1000  
#define ADXL357_ODR_7_8HZ_LPF             0b1001  
#define ADXL357_ODR_3_9HZ_LPF             0b1010  

// #define ADXL357_SPI_10MHZ_SPEED           10000000
#define ADXL357_SPI_10MHZ_SPEED           10*1000*1000
#define ADXL357_SPI_DUMMY_VALUE           0b10101010

#define ADXL357_BUFFER_CAPACITY   32

#define ADXL357_MEASUREMENT_MODE  0

/* FIFO samples/Watermark register settings */
#define ADXL357_FIFO_SAMPLES_BIT       6
#define ADXL357_FIFO_SAMPLES_LENGTH    7

typedef enum{
    X_AXIS = 1,
    Y_AXIS = 2,
    Z_AXIS = 3,
} ADXL357_DIRECTION; 


typedef enum {
    TEN_G = 1,
    TWENTY_G = 2,
    FOURTY_G = 3,
} Adxl_Range;

typedef enum {
    INT_POL_HIGH = 1, 
    INT_POL_LOW = 0, 
} Adxl_Int_Pol; 



class ADXL357 {
  public:
    unsigned long dumTest; 
    uint8_t     fLasEntr; 
    uint8_t     fNewEntr; 
    float     lastFIFO[ADXL357_BUFFER_CAPACITY]; 
    float     newistFIFO[ADXL357_BUFFER_CAPACITY]; 

    ADXL357(uint8_t cS);

    ~ADXL357() {};
    /** begin(),i2c init & set defaule I2C address.
        // @param set i2c_address
     **/
    // int32_t begin(uint8_t dev_addr = DEFAULT_DEV_I2C_ADDRESS);

    // int32_t beginNoReset(uint8_t dev_addr = DEFAULT_DEV_I2C_ADDRESS);

    /** set action enable.
        @param enable_x enable x axis action.When the x axis result above threshold,trigger event.
        @param enable_y enable y axis action.When the y axis result above threshold,trigger event.
        @param enable_z enable z axis action.When the z axis result above threshold,trigger event.
     **/
    void setActEnable(bool enable_x, bool enable_y, bool enable_z);


    uint8_t readDeviceID();
    uint8_t readDeviceVersion(void);

    bool    testConnection(); 

    /** Read x/y/z axis data from register.

     **/
    void readXYZAxisResultData(int32_t& x, int32_t& y, int32_t& z);
    /** Config ADXL357 mode.
        bit2 - DRDY_OFF ,
        bit1 - TEMP-OFF ,
        bit0 - running mode,0 for measurement mode,1 for standby mode.
     **/
    void setPowerCtr(uint8_t val);

    void readTemperature(float& T);

    /** Get status register data.
        bit4 - NVM-BUSY
        bit3 - Activity
        bit2 - FIFO_OVR
        bit1 - FIFO_FULL
        bit0 - DATA_RDY
     **/
    uint8_t getAdxl357Status(void);
    /** Check whether the  status register's first bit is 1.
     **/
    bool checkDataReady(void);

    void resetDevice(void);

    void setFilter(uint8_t filt);
    /** Set ADXL357's full scale range.
        ±10g,±20g,±40g
     **/
    void setFIFOwatermark(uint8_t val); 

    uint8_t getFIFOwatermark(); 

    void setAdxlRange(Adxl_Range range);
    /** Read x/y/z axis data from FIFO.

     **/

    void setIntPol(Adxl_Int_Pol pol); 

    uint8_t saveFIFO(int16_t thresh, ADXL357_DIRECTION dir); 

    void resetFIFO(); 

    uint8_t getFIFOentries();

    /** Set threshold,when measured result over than threshold,trigger event,if corresponding INT function has enabled,trigger interruct event.
        @param acc_g The threshold value,unit is g.
        @param factory Acceleration value corresponding to one acceleration result value,the result value is read from register.

     **/
    void setActThreshold(uint16_t thresh);
    /** Set config INT pin.
     * 

     **/
    void setIntPinMap(uint8_t val);
    /** Event count.event count incresed when axis result value over than threshold.

     **/
    uint8_t getActiveCnt(void);

    void setActiveCnt(uint8_t cnt); 

  private:
    uint8_t bufferSPI[9]; 
    uint32_t _x_data;
    uint32_t _y_data;
    uint32_t _z_data;
    uint8_t  _dev_addr;
    uint8_t _chipSelectPin; 

            /* SPI communication methods */
    void singleByteReadSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t *data); 
    void singleByteWriteSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t value); 

    void twoByteWriteSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint16_t value); 

    void multiByteReadSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t numberOfBytes, uint8_t *dataBuffer); 
    
    void singleBitWriteSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitNum, uint8_t data); 
    void singleBitReadSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitNum, uint8_t *data); 

    void multiBitReadSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitStart, uint8_t length, uint8_t *data); 
    void multiBitWriteSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitStart, uint8_t length, uint8_t data); 

};



#endif
```

**ADXL357_SPI.cpp**

```cpp
/*

    Copyright (c) 2019 Seeed Technology Co., Ltd.
    Website    : www.seeed.cc
    Author     : downey
    Create Time: Jan 2018
    Change Log :

    The MIT License (MIT)

    Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
    of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
    in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
    to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
    copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
    furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

    The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
    all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
    IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
    FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
    AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
    LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
    OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
    THE SOFTWARE.
*/
#include "ADXL357_SPI.h"


/** Constructor **/
ADXL357::ADXL357(uint8_t cS) {

    _chipSelectPin = cS;
    dumTest = 0; 

    pinMode(_chipSelectPin, OUTPUT); 
    digitalWrite(_chipSelectPin, HIGH); 

    SPI.begin();
    resetFIFO(); 
}

bool ADXL357::testConnection() {
    uint8_t id = readDeviceID(); 
    return id == ADXL357_PARTID;
}
// int32_t ADXL357::begin(uint8_t cS) {

//     uint8_t ID = 0;
//     Wire.begin();
//     Wire.setClock(1000000); // Added later to increase speed. Before there was nothing here. 
//     _dev_addr = dev_addr;
//     if (readDeviceID(ID) || (ID != 0xed)) {
//         if (readDeviceID(ID)){
//             // Serial.println("Reading ID failed"); 
//         }
//         // Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(ID, HEX); 
//         // Serial.println("Perform software reset - requires I2C"); 
//         // adxlReset();
//         return -1;
//     }
//     adxlReset();
//     delay(200);
//     return 0;
// }


// int32_t ADXL357::beginNoReset(uint8_t dev_addr) {
//     uint8_t ID = 0;
//     Wire.begin();
//     Wire.setClock(1000000); // Added later to increase speed. Before there was nothing here. 
//     _dev_addr = dev_addr;
//     if (readDeviceID(ID) || (ID != 0xed)) {
//         return -1;
//     }
//     // adxlReset();
//     delay(200);
//     return 0;
// }


/* Interrupt polarity mapping is hosted at the same register address as the "set range" address. Hence both use SET_RANGE_REG_ADDR  */
void ADXL357::setIntPol(Adxl_Int_Pol pol) {
    uint8_t orig;
    singleByteReadSPI(ADXL357_SET_RANGE_REG_ADDR, bufferSPI);
    orig = bufferSPI[0]; 
    // Serial.print("read reg = ");
    // Serial.println(orig);

    orig = (pol << 6) | (orig & ~(1 << 6)); // Use mask. Updated from default in library, Daan. 19.11.2021 

    // orig |= (pol << 6);


    // Serial.println(orig);
    singleByteWriteSPI(ADXL357_SET_RANGE_REG_ADDR, orig);
}


void ADXL357::setAdxlRange(Adxl_Range range) {
    
    singleByteReadSPI(ADXL357_SET_RANGE_REG_ADDR, bufferSPI);
    uint8_t orig = bufferSPI[0];  
    // Serial.print("read reg = ");
    // Serial.println(orig);

    orig = range | (orig & ~(0b00000011)); // Use mask 

    // orig |= range;   // <-- origineel. Is dit een valide manier om een register waarde in te stellen? Lijkt me niet.. |= operatie kan alleen gebruikt worden om een bit aan te zetten, niet uit.. 

    // Serial.print("-> Range register: "); Serial.println(orig, BIN);

    singleByteWriteSPI(ADXL357_SET_RANGE_REG_ADDR, orig);
}


uint8_t ADXL357::getActiveCnt(void) {
    singleByteReadSPI(ADXL357_ACT_COUNT_REG_ADDR, bufferSPI); 
    return bufferSPI[0];
}

void ADXL357::setActiveCnt(uint8_t cnt){
    singleByteWriteSPI(ADXL357_ACT_COUNT_REG_ADDR, cnt); 
}

void ADXL357::resetDevice(void) {
    singleByteWriteSPI(ADXL357_RESET_REG_ADDR, 0x52);
    // check for shadow registers values 

}


void ADXL357::setActThreshold(uint16_t thresh) {
    // int16_t thres = 0;
    // thres = (int16_t)(acc_g / factory);
    // thres >>= 3;

    // uint16_t thres2 = 100; // 2063, 1063, 500, 100  
    // thres = 13300;
    // thres >>= 3;
    // Serial.print("Activity Threshold: "); Serial.println(thres, HEX);

    // Write two bytes, we start with the lowest addres. 
    // return i2cWriteU16(ACT_THRESH_H_REG_ADDR, (uint16_t)thres2);
    twoByteWriteSPI(ADXL357_ACT_THRESH_H_REG_ADDR, thresh);
}

/** set action enable.
    @param enable_x enable x axis action.When the x axis result above threshold,trigger event.
    @param enable_y enable y axis action.When the y axis result above threshold,trigger event.
    @param enable_z enable z axis action.When the z axis result above threshold,trigger event.
 **/
void ADXL357::setActEnable(bool enable_x, bool enable_y, bool enable_z) {
    uint8_t val = 0;
    val = val | (enable_z << 2) | (enable_y << 1) | enable_x;
    singleByteWriteSPI(ADXL357_ACT_EN_REG_ADDR, val);
}

void ADXL357::setIntPinMap(uint8_t val) {
    singleByteWriteSPI(ADXL357_SET_INT_PIN_MAP_REG_ADDR, val);
}

/** Config ADXL357 mode.
    bit2 - DRDY_OFF ,
    bit1 - TEMP-OFF ,
    bit0 - running mode,0 for measurement mode,1 for standby mode.
 **/
void ADXL357::setPowerCtr(uint8_t val) {
    singleByteWriteSPI(ADXL357_POWER_CTR_REG_ADDR, val);
}

void ADXL357::readTemperature(float& T) {
    // int32_t ret = 0;
    int16_t temperatureLSB = 0;

    multiByteReadSPI(ADXL357_TEMPERATURE_REG_ADDR, 2, bufferSPI); 

    uint16_t temH = 0b00001111 & (uint16_t)bufferSPI[0]; 
    uint16_t temL = bufferSPI[1]; 
    
    uint16_t val = (temH << 8) | temL; 

    temperatureLSB = val;
    T = 25 + (temperatureLSB - 1852) / (-9.05); // output temperature in celcius 
    // return 0;
}

void ADXL357::setFilter(uint8_t filt) {  // See datasheet 
    /*011 <-> 15.545*10^-3*ODR |  0011 <-> 500HZ&125HZ   | total = 0b00110011 or 0x33*/ 

    /*000 <-> Not applicable no high pass filter | 0011 <-> 500HZ&125HZ \ total = 0b00000011*/

    /* 110 <-> Lowest LPF there is | .... */ 


    singleByteWriteSPI(ADXL357_FILTER_REG_ADDR, filt);
}

void ADXL357::setFIFOwatermark(uint8_t val){
    multiBitWriteSPI(ADXL357_FIFO_SAMPLES_REG, ADXL357_FIFO_SAMPLES_BIT, ADXL357_FIFO_SAMPLES_LENGTH, val);
}
uint8_t ADXL357::getFIFOwatermark(){
    uint8_t val; 
    multiBitReadSPI(ADXL357_FIFO_SAMPLES_REG, ADXL357_FIFO_SAMPLES_BIT, ADXL357_FIFO_SAMPLES_LENGTH, &val); 
    return val; 
}


uint8_t ADXL357::getFIFOentries(void) {
    
    singleByteReadSPI(ADXL357_FIFO_ENTRY_REG_ADDR, bufferSPI);
    uint8_t out = 0b01111111 & bufferSPI[0]; 

    return out; 
}

/* when calling this function specify the threshold of activity, 
and the direction that we want to measure in */
uint8_t ADXL357::saveFIFO(int16_t thresh, ADXL357_DIRECTION dir) {

    int32_t val = 0; 
    int16_t j = 0; 

    /* Transfer 'newist' FIFO into the 'last' one. */
    for (int i=0; i < fNewEntr; i++){
        lastFIFO[i]    =   newistFIFO[i]; 
    }
    fLasEntr = fNewEntr; 

    /* Transfer everything on ADXL into the 'newist' fifo buffer. */
    fNewEntr = min((getFIFOentries() / 3), ADXL357_BUFFER_CAPACITY); 
    float tempAcc    = 0.0;
    readTemperature(tempAcc);
    float scaleFactor = 1.0/(25600.0 + (tempAcc - 25.0)*2.56);

    for (int i = 0; i < fNewEntr; i++){
        
        multiByteReadSPI(ADXL357_FIFO_DATA_REG_ADDR, 9, bufferSPI); 
        switch(dir){
            case X_AXIS: 
                val = ((uint32_t)bufferSPI[0] << 12) | ((uint32_t)bufferSPI[1] << 4) | ((uint32_t)bufferSPI[2] >> 4);
                if (val & 0x80000) {
                    val = (val & 0x7ffff) - 0x80000;
                }
                break; 
            case Y_AXIS: 
                val = ((uint32_t)bufferSPI[3] << 12) | ((uint32_t)bufferSPI[4] << 4) | ((uint32_t)bufferSPI[5] >> 4);
                if (val & 0x80000) {
                    val = (val & 0x7ffff) - 0x80000;
                }
                break;         
            case Z_AXIS:
                val = ((uint32_t)bufferSPI[6] << 12) | ((uint32_t)bufferSPI[7] << 4) | ((uint32_t)bufferSPI[8] >> 4);
                if (val & 0x80000) {
                    val = (val & 0x7ffff) - 0x80000;
                }
                break; 
            default: 
                // error, nothing specified
                break; 
        }
        
        newistFIFO[i]   =   (float)val*scaleFactor*9.81; 

        /* Take note of the number of times threshold is exceeded */
        if (abs(val) > thresh){
            j++; 
        }
        dumTest++; 
    }

    return j; 

}

void ADXL357::resetFIFO(){

    for(uint16_t i=0; i < ADXL357_BUFFER_CAPACITY;  i++){       
        
        lastFIFO[i]     =   0.0; 

        newistFIFO[i]   =   0.0;
    }
}

uint8_t ADXL357::readDeviceID(void) {     
    singleByteReadSPI(ADXL357_DEV_ID_REG_ADDR, bufferSPI);
    return bufferSPI[0]; 
}

uint8_t ADXL357::readDeviceVersion(void) {
    singleByteReadSPI(ADXL357_DEV_VERSION_ID_REG_ADDR, bufferSPI);
    return bufferSPI[0]; 
}

uint8_t ADXL357::getAdxl357Status(void) {
    singleByteReadSPI(ADXL357_STATUS_REG_ADDR, bufferSPI);
    return bufferSPI[0]; 
    
}

bool ADXL357::checkDataReady(void) {
    uint8_t stat = getAdxl357Status();
    // Serial.println(",,,");
    // Serial.println(stat,HEX);
    // Serial.println(",,,");
    return stat & 0x01; // stat is a byte in this case, and 0x01 is 1 (true?). Here it's maybe being used as a bitwise operator? stat & 0b00000001 = only  1 if  the last bit of stat is 1 (i.e. DATA_RDY)
}

/*********************************************************************************************************************/
/*********************************************************************************************************************/

/* ---------- SPI READ FUNCTIONS ------------------------ */

void ADXL357::singleByteReadSPI( uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t *data) {
    multiByteReadSPI(regAddr, 1, data);
}

void ADXL357::multiByteReadSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t numberOfBytes, uint8_t *dataBuffer){


    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(ADXL357_SPI_10MHZ_SPEED, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));

    digitalWrite(_chipSelectPin,LOW);

    uint8_t readMBaddr; 

    /* The LSBit specifies a read or write. Write is low bit, read is high bit */
    readMBaddr = (regAddr << 1) | 0b00000001;


    SPI.transfer(readMBaddr);

    for (uint8_t k = 0; k < numberOfBytes; k++ ){
      dataBuffer[k] = SPI.transfer(ADXL357_SPI_DUMMY_VALUE);
    }

    digitalWrite(_chipSelectPin,HIGH);
    // delayMicroseconds(4); 

    SPI.endTransaction();

}

/* Read a single bit from an 8 bit register */
void ADXL357::singleBitReadSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitNum, uint8_t *data) {
    uint8_t b;
    singleByteReadSPI(regAddr, &b);
    *data = (b & (1 << bitNum)) >> bitNum; // the first element of an array is the same as it's pointer, right?
}

/** Read multiple bits from an 8-bit device register. */
void ADXL357::multiBitReadSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitStart, uint8_t length, uint8_t *data) {
    // 01101001 read byte
    // 76543210 bit numbers
    //    xxx   args: bitStart=4, length=3
    //    010   masked
    //   -> 010 shifted
    uint8_t b;

    singleByteReadSPI(regAddr, &b);

    uint8_t mask = ((1 << length) - 1) << (bitStart - length + 1);
    b &= mask;
    b >>= (bitStart - length + 1);
    *data = b;

}

/* ---------- SPI WRITE FUNCTIONS ------------------------ */

void ADXL357::singleByteWriteSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t value) {

    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(ADXL357_SPI_10MHZ_SPEED, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));

    // take the SS pin low to select the chip:
    digitalWrite(_chipSelectPin,LOW);

    //  send in the first byte. This must contain: R/W bit, MB (multi byte) bit, and address of register to read from
    uint8_t writeMBaddr = (regAddr << 1) | 0b00000000; //  From left to right: write (0), not multibyte (0), and then a bunch of zeros


    //  send in the first byte. This must contain: R/W bit, MB (multi byte) bit, and address of register to write to
    SPI.transfer(writeMBaddr);

    //  send the second byte. This must contain: the byte of data you want to write.
    SPI.transfer(value);

    // take the SS pin high to de-select the chip:
    digitalWrite(_chipSelectPin,HIGH);

    // end transaction
    SPI.endTransaction();

}

void ADXL357::twoByteWriteSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint16_t value){
    
    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(ADXL357_SPI_10MHZ_SPEED, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));

    // take the SS pin low to select the chip:
    digitalWrite(_chipSelectPin,LOW);

    //  send in the first byte. This must contain: R/W bit, MB (multi byte) bit, and address of register to read from
    uint8_t writeMBaddr = (regAddr << 1) | 0b00000000; //  From left to right: write (0), not multibyte (0), and then a bunch of zeros

    //  send in the first byte. This must contain: R/W bit, MB (multi byte) bit, and address of register to write to
    SPI.transfer(writeMBaddr);

    // the byte located at the lower address, is the higher byte part of the number 
    uint8_t lowerAddressByte    = value >> 8; 
    uint8_t higherAddressByte   = value; 

    //  send the second byte. This must contain: the byte of data you want to write.
    SPI.transfer(lowerAddressByte);
    SPI.transfer(higherAddressByte);


    // take the SS pin high to de-select the chip:
    digitalWrite(_chipSelectPin,HIGH);

    // end transaction
    SPI.endTransaction();

}

/* Write a single bit to a 8 bit register  */
void ADXL357::singleBitWriteSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitNum, uint8_t data) {
    uint8_t b;
    singleByteReadSPI(regAddr, &b);
    b = (data != 0) ? (b | (1 << bitNum)) : (b & ~(1 << bitNum));
    singleByteWriteSPI(regAddr, b);
}


void ADXL357::multiBitWriteSPI(uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitStart, uint8_t length, uint8_t data) {
    //      010 value to write
    // 76543210 bit numbers
    //    xxx   args: bitStart=4, length=3
    // 00011100 mask byte
    // 10101111 original value (sample)
    // 10100011 original & ~mask
    // 10101011 masked | value
    uint8_t b;

    singleByteReadSPI(regAddr, &b); 

    uint8_t mask = ((1 << length) - 1) << (bitStart - length + 1);
    data <<= (bitStart - length + 1); // shift data into correct position
    data &= mask; // zero all non-important bits in data
    b &= ~(mask); // zero all important bits in existing byte
    b |= data; // combine data with existing byte
    
    singleByteWriteSPI(regAddr, b);

}
```

N.B. The forum is not letting me add more characters, so I can't add the ADXL373 library files.

Comment: The schematics do not indicate any serious issues. Have you done any measurements or debugging on the circuit, or did you simply write code and it does not work? For all we know, the problem might be in code so chip select does not toggle at all, or the chip has a short circuit or missing power supply. If you have done any measurements to see what works and what doesn't, add them to question, also code comparison used to communicate between two chips, or IO pin init of chip select pins can be made to find software bugs.

Comment: Hi @Justme, thanks for suggestion. Added code etc. Due to character limitation I can't add all the files.

Comment: I discovered what the problem was. Wong pin assignment in software  for CS for ADXL357 (*sigh*). Not sure how to proceed with this question. Answer it myself and accept answer, or delete it since it's not much value to others?